# ApplescriptObjC Path To Folder

Tags: applescript

I am currently setting up an ApplescriptObjC application. Whenever I try other methods, it screws up. I'm trying to set it up where a shell script uses the mv command to move a file from the "Files" directory to the  /usr/bin/ folder. I think it would go a little something like: `do shell script "sudo mv " & path & "/Files/ /usr/bin/"` where path would be the path to me. I have tried the path to me and posix and other stuff, just doesn't work. ![The Files folder contains a file I want to move to /usr/bin]  Image of where the folder is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUX6w.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the folder `Files` in your screenshot is a virtual folder in Xcode (yellow).
You have to create a real folder (blue). The easiest way is to drag a folder in Finder to the Xcode sidebar and select "Create folder references"

To use `sudo` in AppleScript append `with administrator privileges` to the `do shell script` line. You will be prompted to enter an admin password.

This code moves(!) the files to `/usr/bin`. If you want to copy (duplicate) the files use `cp -r` instead of `mv`

```
   set filesFolder to (current application's NSBundle's mainBundle()'s resourcePath()'s stringByAppendingPathComponent:"Languages") as text
   tell application "System Events" to set filesToMove to name of files of folder filesFolder
   repeat with aFile in filesToMove
     do shell script "/bin/mv " & quoted form of (filesFolder & "/" & aFile) & space & "/usr/bin/" with administrator privileges
   end repeat
```